# Regex to find multiple values between two words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to retrieve multiple values between two words, delimiting a specific part of the text. The pattern is this:

```
(^\d\d\d\d)\D+
```

I've tried a lot of regex, but I was not successful.

Below is an example of an attempt that is not working, because it is only returning the first value.

```
Livro[\s\S]*?(^\d\d\d\d)\D+[\s\S]*(?=em moeda corrente)
```

The text where I am trying to apply the regex is as follows. In bold the values I want to retrieve.

**UPDATE
I changed the example because sometimes the first four digits don't have the '/ dd' after them.**

---

CERTIDAO DE DIVIDA ATIVA Nr:XXXXXXXXX 6A

Inscrigao Pessoa Receita

5588 39783 03 -1SS VARIAVEL

Dispositivo Legal do Principal
03 - Artigos 55, 57, 58, 59, 63, 64, 151 e 153, no subiteém 14.01 da Lista de Servicos e na Tabela 03, inciso Ill, da Lei
Complementar n° 12/1994, com alteragé6es dadas pelas Leis Complementares Municipais n° 56/1997, 116/2000,
196/2002, 217/2003, 270/2006, 314/2008, 320/2008, 399/2011 e 502/2015, 538/2017 e artigo 4° da Lei Complementar
n° 4124/2000.

Livro: 14 _ Folha: 17583 a Data: 18/04/201 9 - a
Doc.--Receita -Origam do Débite Principal. Corregao. “AcréscimoD.A Multa == dures. Total

**2016** 03 = =ISS VARIAVEL 36,80 6,47 2,16 4,33 20,33 70,09

**2016** 03 ISS VARIAVEL 116,00 20,38 6,82 13,64 62,74 219,58

**2016** 03 ISS VARIAVEL 340,00 59,74 19,99 39,97 179,88 639,58

**2016** G3 ISS VARIAVEL 246,40 43,29 14,48 28,97 127,46 466,60

**2016**/10 O03 ISS VARIAVEL 56,00 9,84 3,29 6,59 28,31 104,03

**2016**/11 03 ISS VARIAVEL 623,84 109,61 36,67 73,35 308,05 1.161 52

**2016**/12 03 ISS VARIAVEL 20,40 3,58 4,20 2,40 * 9,83 37,41

TOTAL, em moeda corrente, atualizado até: 23/06/2020 2.682,81
A) Atualizag&o Monetaria: artigos 153, paragrafo 1°, 200, | e 209, todos da Lei Complementar Municipal n° 12/94; artigo 4°, da Lei Complementar Municipal n°
1124/2000.

---

I'm testing here https://regex101.com/r/tzgGVT/2 (**updated**)

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Essentially this `Livro[\s\S]*?^` regex will never match anything. What have you really tried ?

Comment: You might use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) `(?:^Livro.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}/\d).*)*\r?\n|\G)(?=(?:\d{4}/\d.*\r?\n)*TOTAL, em moeda corrente\b)(\d{4})/\d+.*\r?\n`  https://regex101.com/r/Gs9cvP/1

Comment: I tried `(^\d\d\d\d)` to catch four digits in the begining of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could make use of the [regex PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) using the `\G` anchor to get the values in bold in capture group 1.

```
(?:^Livro.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}/\d).*)*\r?\n|\G)(\d{4})/\d+.*\r?\n(?=(?:\d{4}/\d.*\r?\n)*.*?\bem moeda corrente\b)
```

*In parts*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^Livro.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}/\d).*)*\r?\n` Match start and lines that don't start with 4 digits `/` and digit
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(\d{4})` Capture **group 1**, match 4 digits
- `/\d+.*\r?\n` Match `/` and 1+ digits followed by the rest of the line
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:\d{4}/\d.*\r?\n)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a line the starts with 4 digits `/` and digit
  - `.*?\bem moeda corrente\b` Match a line that contains `em moeda corrente`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cbR8Wb/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##hVVdbuM2EH6uTzH1Q2G5jMwfiRJTGIGwThcGnE2RuEEfhBaMzPUSkEVDUoK2uwv0IL2A3/YM65v0IulQlltvUqACJAzJ@b75p7a/te9cJZ6e7Gbr6hZqsza/DgZb3bamrmAK9XB0cf7zwj7WLhyjmNcXeTW6@DpfvY8@TvJVEI6Dcbf5IX8djLrtAPe/Dce96tSjeu1@MxiH44v83mxg48xKQ@Hq2lStye@D4WDQoNnR8NXlzXI@y65hdgmz@R2KkC3ndxm8qc9/Oj4gs7zKq@Hgq@G8aorarrWDH0zTOA03pjC21cfzOE5TECpJBVABZ@z2Fu6ym3l2d7k4qsxss3WNbe2jg4VZ6xJWyFbbqrBbXR50PBayurVr10AcE4gTfFN8FQEp8I0IsJiBwS8uKwfNw71tzX63ARaFlAEGvLBNq2Fl4NbUj7ZAKgOVhqW@N6VG/wh4o42DeVmSDmDswf4rt9mWZoPZ0jVUnz8B4xOmFBot3AZ0iWXT6/1OmgZhK93AFhkbj2/gFIvnVw@V9ZHhiSeKpSfCaBiTE04pJQeLTHVLToCzxEvoHU@olyQBwSIvYQIEp0dJKZSYz0FMuRd9nkTqpQQ3dZc@iNDoIbQvPDtY9R5FjHfkNDxWqOvDc8wj/ALfu/KdRjmJsaQaZrr1q3RCPYaBwjrpvq6uCM/O@n6As2vfJhtf29l@50vzb41D9ARbEbsohL/@@DMr6v2uKezGzcIM81UifDqF1QOmL4Sla49dgQblRPrGmsJ0ftJaICRJKUgSJcAJkxARIYBT/00ooeoEn3j8F2CsBKG0U0@RI@XABJERSE6SCMuhSJyeEKQvCEREPQH2JuqjulJYHKISzJoiOA9SPKNQ8PoZBY/QeQqRIFxh4kmUAk87Cp6QCAOSkkh6QsEoXD/3I@7iQJMRdDySxMrTCAaMRoSKUzx7EYbkwkMZVUQyn1KZQCKIiEFgv9EYWMjwIOanNPwFDeYRIxEYMZaBY179cuzdEiAwGHaAL6@X2YLAi9uJgG4fdGl/19g6ut3vzoGLCfXT4clCmXKS9hxZAFmvvP7GwZWrDLa2xQ7V/d3R3Q5bjdNa67cO2OdPOFY4dPABJ4RjpNC6lWv@a0L@mdzyeAOo6LuTqSL/D@pH@2TAhgFe@zgH7aj7B4RvbbXSZTnqfwUEGnL4O4RXPy6W88X8zWUQPD39DQ)

```
Example code

import regex

pattern = r"(?:^Livro.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}/\d).*)*\r?\n|\G)(\d{4})/\d+.*\r?\n(?=(?:\d{4}/\d.*\r?\n)*.*?\bem moeda corrente\b)"

print(regex.findall(pattern, s, regex.MULTILINE))
```

*Output*

```
['2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016']
```

Comment: Thanks. Really not easy one for me ;-)

Comment: @LucianoZanuz For your updated link, you might use `(?:^Livro.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}[ /]).*)*\r?\n|\G)(\d{4})[ /].*\r?\n(?=(?:\d{4}[ /].*\r?\n)*.*?\bem moeda corrente\b)` https://regex101.com/r/w7IY0A/1

Answer (score 0):

I think the complete pattern you are looking for is a year/month where year is four digits and month is 1 or 2 digits, not *more*, so followed by a [space]. In regular expression form:

```
import re

found = re.findall(r'(\d\d\d\d)/\d\d? ', text)
print(found)
```

Outputs:

```
['2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016']
```

Or if you want the entire line for which the expression matches, just leave out the parentheses:

```
found = re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d/\d\d? .*', text)
for line in found: print(line)
```

Outputs:

```
2016/6 03 = =ISS VARIAVEL 36,80 6,47 2,16 4,33 20,33 70,09
2016/7 03 ISS VARIAVEL 116,00 20,38 6,82 13,64 62,74 219,58
2016/8 03 ISS VARIAVEL 340,00 59,74 19,99 39,97 179,88 639,58
2016/9 G3 ISS VARIAVEL 246,40 43,29 14,48 28,97 127,46 466,60
2016/10 O03 ISS VARIAVEL 56,00 9,84 3,29 6,59 28,31 104,03
2016/11 03 ISS VARIAVEL 623,84 109,61 36,67 73,35 308,05 1.161 52
2016/12 03 ISS VARIAVEL 20,40 3,58 4,20 2,40 * 9,83 37,41
```

Or split the text in two by a marker string (e.g. 'Livro') and search in the second part for 4 digits immediately after a newline character (is beginning of a line)

```
parts = text.split('Livro')
found = re.findall(r'\n(\d\d\d\d)', parts[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's important to delimit the part of the text where I should extract the pattern, because I can have the same pattern in another part of the text. And I want to return just the four digit in the begining of the line, because sometimes I have just the year and not the year/month. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `findall()` method of the `re` module. Moreover, the following path I think is the one that you're looking for: `'\n(\d+)\/(?=[\s\S]+ em moeda corrente)'`

```
>>> re.findall('\n(\d+)\/(?=[\s\S]+ em moeda corrente)', text)
['2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016']
```

Try it out at: https://regex101.com/r/RoOB0t/2

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's important to delimit the part of the text where I should extract the pattern, because I can have the same pattern in another part of the text. Any suggestion?

Comment: "Total em moeda corrente" at the end would be enough as delimiter?

Comment: Yes, it's ok as the final delimiter.

Comment: Thanks again. I updated the example in the question because sometimes the string doesn't have the '/dd' after the four first digits. And it's important to consider the 'Livro' string as the first delimiter.